# Administer Users by Role module - show users

Tags: views, users, importing-exporting

I'm using [Administer Users by Role](https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module and I crated a view of users.
That view displays all the users. 
Lets assume there is 'Admin', 'Editor' & 'Member' roles. 
Admin can see all the users.
Editor can see only Members (not other Editors and not the admin).
I need that so I can use Views-Data-Export module.

How to create such a view? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is correct or not but you can try this,

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) 
{
 global $user;
 $role=implode(', ', array_slice($user->roles, 1));//get the current user role
if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') 
{
  switch ($role) {
    case 'administrator':
//  drupal_set_message("administrator");
     // $query->add_where(); put your where condition
     // $view->query->set_group_operator('OR');
        break;
    case 'editor':
//  drupal_set_message("editor");
     // $query->add_where(); put your where condition
     // $view->query->set_group_operator('OR');
        break;
    case 'Member':
    //  drupal_set_message("Member");
      // $query->add_where(); put your where condition
     // $view->query->set_group_operator('OR');
        break;
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: If it's a Member how to cancel the query?

Comment: If it is member than call the empty view result..or you can make a condition on where clause.